# cannot access $scope variables in controller and view - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to bind few drop-downs in a controller(GridSearchCtrl) i.e. in another controller(DiplomaProgramGridCtrl). i was trying the below code but it is giving me error 
***$scope.advSearch is not defined***

```
  DiplomaProgramController.controller('GridSearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'DiplomaProgramService', 
      function ($scope, DiplomaProgramService) {

        $scope.loadDropDowns = function ($scope) {
          DiplomaProgramService.loadDropDowns('abcd').then(function (DiplomaProgram) {
            $scope.advSearch.depts = DiplomaProgram.depts;
            $scope.advSearch.degreesList = DiplomaProgram.degreesList;
            // Here it shows the list perfectly
            console.log($scope.advSearch.degreesList);
          });
       };
       $scope.loadDropDowns($scope);
       // Here it generates error i.e. $scope.advSearch is undefined
       console.log($scope.advSearch.degreesList);
}]);
```

The view looks like this

```
    <select id="ddlDegrees" name="degrees" ng-model="advSearch.DegreeLevelID" ng-options="a.DegreeLevelID as a.DegreeLevelName for a in degreesList" required>
        <option value="">-- select --</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that what's inside the .then(function) is asynchronous, so your console.log is executed before $scope.advSearch is defined.

Try doing this instead (I don't really know how promises work yet so $scope.$apply might not be relevant in that case at all):

```
DiplomaProgramService.loadDropDowns('abcd').then(function (DiplomaProgram) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.advSearch.depts = DiplomaProgram.depts;
        $scope.advSearch.degreesList = DiplomaProgram.degreesList;
        // Here it shows the list perfectly
        console.log($scope.advSearch.degreesList);
    }
});
```

It still won't work with the console.log, but it should tell Angular that your scope has been updated and make your view work.